# cache queries with firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I know I can add { source: "cache" } to read from the cache 
but in this case what I need is to persist data on the server

```
export const getPeople = () => {
    return db
        .collection("cities")
        .doc("SF")
        .collection("people")
        .get();
};
```

every user hitting the site will run that query. I want to cache for a few minutes at least. is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The client API will not conditionally cache for you.  Either it uses the cache, or it does not.  (The only condition it applies is falling back to the cache if there is no network connectivity.)

What you can do instead is implement your own cache on top of the API, which is non-trivial to do.  Even an in-memory cache will require you to implement the logic of checking to see if a cached snapshot is within whatever time bounds are acceptable without a refresh.